# SimpleXMLElement return weird XML structure

Tags: php, sql, xml, simplexml

I'm struggling with SimpleXMLElement for quite some time and I can't figure out how to output a well formatted XML document.

With a SQL query, I retrieve some data as XML format.

```
select S_MODELE, S_ID from stock FOR XML RAW ('Product'), ROOT ('Products'),  ELEMENTS"
```

In php, I have a variable called `$values` that is equal to this :

```
<products>
  <product>
    <S_MODELE>Some text</S_MODELE>
    <S_ID>1</S_ID>
  </product>
  <product>
    <S_MODELE>Some text</S_MODELE>
    <S_ID>2</S_ID>
  </product>
  <product>
    <S_MODELE>Some text</S_MODELE>
    <S_ID>3</S_ID>
  </product>
</products>
```

I'm then trying to output a **properly formatted XML file** in the browser :

```
  header('Content-Type: text/xml');
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($values);
  echo $xml->asXML();
```

And I get something like this :

[image: Bad XML Output]

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot does not match the output example. It looks like you have multiple XML documents as text inside another XML structure.

Be aware that if you look at an XML as HTML in the browser you will see only the text content. In this case the inner XML documents.

If `$values` already contains the XML document, you can just `echo $values`. Here is no need to load it into a DOM or SimpleXMLElement, just to serialize it again.

Comment: The thing is that even with a simple echo $value, I have the same problem. Looks like multiple XML documents nested.

Comment: Because the error is before that. $values already contains the XML shown in the screenshot. SimpleXMLElement will not modify the XML that way see: https://eval.in/296417

Comment: In fact my query return an object `object(stdClass)#6 (2) { ["schema"]=> string(492) "" ["any"]=> string(853)` when I echo `$values->any` with the proper Header type I already get a XML document.